# Access query count with criteria

Tags: ms-access

I have an query to filter result like image

[image]

I've tried to write query with DCOUNT but not work

```
SELECT LANG, Count(LANG) AS [TOTAL], 
DCount("[B]","TEST","[B]='B'") AS B, DCount("[C]","TEST","[C]='C'") AS C, DCount("[D]","TEST","[D]='D'") AS D
FROM TEST
GROUP BY LANG;
```

This query will return all column 'B','C','D' is 1

I want to count only for field if have value, if empty, just let it empty like picture
How i can do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try conditional aggregation using the `SUM` function with `IIF`:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(LANG) AS TOTAL,
    SUM(IIF([B] = 'B', 1, NULL)) AS B,
    SUM(IIF([C] = 'C', 1, NULL)) AS C,
    SUM(IIF([D] = 'D', 1, NULL)) AS D
FROM TEST
GROUP BY
    LANG;
```

The reason for using the `SUM` function rather than `COUNT`, is that the former does not ignore `NULL` values, in the event that every value in the sum be `NULL`.  That is, should a given aggregation have no matches, the above would return `NULL` (empty) for the sum, whereas `COUNT` or `DCOUNT` (which internally uses `COUNT`) would actually return zero.